# C# 5 and async timers

Tags: c#, .net, timer, async-await, c#-5.0

Is there a new Timer API somewhere that allows me to do this?

```
await timer.wait(500);
```

Basically, to sleep for X ms and then resume execution of the rest of a function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try use

```
await Task.Delay(500);
```

Comment: As you'd expect, it also has overloads to pass in a CancellationToken in case you're in a UI operation and need to support cancellation. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160377(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 10):

I have a helper that I really like, just to add a bit of readability:

```
public static Task Seconds(this int seconds)
{
    return Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0,0,seconds));
}
```

This allows me to use something like

```
await 5.Seconds();
```

You could easily make similar extension methods for milliseconds, minutes, hours, or whatever.