# Delaying code execution by time, Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making this card matching game, and my code is to flip the card face up, by drawing the card image onto a rectangle shape.

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/Cards/Suit.png", UriKind.Absolute));
ib.ImageSource = bi;
rectangle.Fill = ib;
```

Now, if the player has flipped two cards, and they don't match, I want the game to wait a couple of seconds, and then flip them back over. This is the code I used for the delay.

```
DateTime dttmCurrentTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
while (DateTime.Now < dttmCurrentTime){ }
```

I know, it's the least elegant thing ever. Anyway, all of this is in the same method, and the problem is that the drawing of the image on the rectangle doesn't occur until AFTER the while loop is finished, for some reason. I don't understand way, this is all single-threaded, it seems like the rectangle drawing should occur first. Is there a better way to do this, or a way to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746555/c-sharp-5-and-async-timers

Comment: That was fast. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using a timer?